# Managing Shadow Copies with WMIC - Creation, Restoration, and Deletion

Tags: windows, backup, restore, wmic, shadow-copy

We are currently using the command mentioned below to create a shadow copy using WMIC.

`wmic shadowcopy call create volume=<DRIVE>:\`

Our specific requirement is to restore only particular folders and files from the drive. To accomplish this, we have created a shortcut and employed Robocopy. Are there any optimized approaches for file or folder-specific restoration?

Furthermore, when it comes to deleting the shadow copy, is there a specific age limit or expiry option? If not, will we be able to identify who has created the copy? If not, as we would need the shadow copy ID to achieve this, is there a more secure way to store this information at the OS level without introducing any security threats?